# Adding a condition in jQuery submit() function

Tags: jquery, submit

I have a registration form for multiple people to register. In my submit() jQuery function, I want to check if each email address matches its corresponding confirmation email adress:

```
jQuery('[name="email_address\\[\\]"]').each(function(){
    var email = jQuery(this).val();
    var confirmation_email = jQuery(this).parents('.section').next('.section').children('input.confirm_email').val();
    if ( email != confirmation_email ) {
        alert("At least one email address does't match confirmation email address. Please check all email addresses");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Problem is, the `return false` only interrupts the execution of my `each()` function, not the `submit()` function. How to interrupt `submit()` function execution from within the `each()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare some variable outside the `each` and assign `false` to it if emails are not equal. Then return this variable

```
var emailCorrect = true;

jQuery('[name="email_address\\[\\]"]').each(function(){
    var email = jQuery(this).val();
    var confirmation_email = jQuery(this)
                            .parents('.section')
                            .next('.section')
                            .children('input.confirm_email')
                            .val();
    if ( email != confirmation_email ) {
        alert("At least one email address does't match confirmation email address. Please check all email addresses");
        emailCorrect= false;
    }
});

return emailCorrect;
```